# Dilution factor and ICP

Tags: analytical-chemistry, spectroscopy

I did total digestion on a $\pu{0.05 g}$ sample and had a final volume of $\pu{10 mL}$ once it was digested. I then took $\pu{5 mL}$ of this $\pu{10 mL}$ solution and diluted it to $\pu{10 mL}$ with water for ICP analysis.

The ICP gives a concentration of $\pu{1.5E-3 mg L^-1}.$ I haven't accounted for the dilution factor yet. Would it be $\pu{10.00 mL}/(\pu{0.05 g}) = \pu{200 mL g^-1}$ and then   $\pu{10 mL}/(\pu{5 mL}) = 2,$ so the overall dilution factor would be $200\times 2 = 400?$

So the actual concentration would be $400\times\pu{1.5E-3 mg L^-1} = \pu{0.6 mg L^-1}?$

Comment: You just diluted by a factor of two, so just double the concentration from the ICP determination. What element are you looking at with the ICP, by the way?

Comment: Are you really trying to find the mass of your determined element of interest that is contained to your 50 mg sample? If so, then it is just 30 ng, i.e., 0.003 mg/L times 10 mL.